# Card layout with tabs inside panel using extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs5

When I create a new extjs panel with a Card layout inside an other panel I will got the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClsOnOver' of null"

What is this error mean and how can I fix this?

Panel inside the: this is the page where I want to show a tabbed panel inside the item of this panel.

```
Ext.define('app.view.dashboard.DashboardLeft', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
xtype: 'dashboardLeft',

requires: [
    'Ext.layout.container.VBox',
    'OPENhrm.view.dashboard.widget.*'
],

controller: 'dashboard-dashboardLeft',

viewModel: {
    type: 'dashboard-dashboardLeft'
},

layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    pack: 'start',
    align: 'stretch'
},

defaults: {
    frame: false
},

items: [{
    flex: 1,
    xtype: 'taskboard' // show tabbed panel
}]
});
```

The tabbed panel:

```
Ext.define("app.view.dashboard.widget.Taskboard", {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

requires: [
    'Ext.layout.container.Card'
],

xtype: 'taskboard',
controller: 'taskboard',

viewModel: { 
    type: 'taskboard' 
},

id: 'taskboard',

// tabs
items:[{
    title: 'tab 1',
    html: 'test 1'
}, {
    title: 'tab 2',
    html: 'test 2'
}, {
    title: 'tab 3',
    html: 'test 3'
}]
});
```

Comment: What is the jquery tag for? You should never mix ExtJs and jquery in the same app.

Comment: This error it's because you are calling a method of a object which is null. That's probably because you are not recovering from the controller or from whatever you are doing it, the object correctly in this case i think is the "taskboard".